# Meauring the differences between groups

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, hypothesis-testing

There is a metric that counted by different groups. What is the best way to categorize or show the statistical difference between groups? Is ANOVA the best way to evaluate this?

The dataset looks like,

```
             vendor 1      vendor 2      vendor 3      vendor 4      vendor 5     
pass            7             6             4             17            9
no pass         3             5             1             2             3
```

Comment: What "statistical difference" do you want to show?

Comment: Hi, @Dave I want to find a way to evaluate if the different vendors can affect the pass rate. I have drawn a stacked bar chart for this. And trying to find a way that can measure the degree of the difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "measure the degree of difference"? You have that vendor 1 has a 70% pass range and vendor 3 has an 80% pass rate. You know what that difference is. What is left for you to calculate for that pair? (You could do that for the other pairs, certainly.) // Because the response variable is a binary pass/fail variable, the classical ANOVA will not work, if that ANOVA problem (assessing if the means of these groups equal or not) is what interests you.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much@Dave I forgot the constraint about the response. For now, I guess the only thing I can do is build crosstab on this data. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What do you want to know? Are you looking for a hypothesis test that the pass rates for the vendors are the same?

Comment: @Dave Yes, it is.

Comment: A chi-squared test is a standard way to do this. The usual software packages like R and Python/SciPy have this implemented.